# How to display all elements in vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

When I try to display all elements in the vector, it only display name of dealer, and number of dealer, but number of cars is MISSING! So how do I display the whole vector completely?

I declare a vector in Main and pass it to the readIn and display function.
or is there something wrong with the push_back?

however when I use debugger
[image]

The result Suppose be like:

```
John Elway Dodge    123    2
Tesla Cherry Creek    234    1
```

However it is now like:

```
John Elway Dodge    123
Tesla Cherry Creek    234
```

The "2" and the "1" is missing for some reason.
Here is my code. Thankyou in advance.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
  class Dealer
{
private:
    string dealerName;
    int dealerNumber;
    int numberOfCars;

public:

    Dealer();
    Dealer(string _dealerName, int _dealerNumber, int _numberOfCars);

    void readIn(vector <Dealer> &tempDealerOne);
};

void display(vector <Dealer> &tempDealerOne);
int main() 
{
    vector <Dealer> dealerOne;
    Dealer dealer1;
    dealer1.readIn(dealerOne);
    display(dealerOne);
}

// function to read in data
void Dealer::readIn (vector <Dealer> &tempDealerOne)
 {
    const int size = 23;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("in.txt");
    string tempName[size];
    int tempDealerNum[size],tempCarNum[size];
    Dealer temp1;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        getline(infile,tempName[i]);
        if(i == 0)
        {
            infile >> tempDealerNum[i];
            infile >> tempCarNum[i];
            temp1.dealerName = tempName[i];
            temp1.dealerNumber = tempDealerNum[i];
            // this 
            temp1.numberOfCars = tempCarNum[i];
            // assign the data to vector
            tempDealerOne.push_back(temp1);
        }
        if(i == 14)
        {
            infile >> tempDealerNum[i];
            infile >> tempCarNum[i];
            temp1.dealerName = tempName[i];
            temp1.dealerNumber = tempDealerNum[i];
            temp1.numberOfCars = tempCarNum[i];
            // assign the data to vector
            tempDealerOne.push_back(temp1);
        }

    }
    // read in data store in vector
    // then pass it to Dealer class
     infile.close();
 }

 void display(vector <Dealer> &tempDealerOne)
{
    // what is the problem
    for(int i = 0; i < tempDealerOne.size(); i++)
    cout << tempDealerOne[0]<< "\n";
}
```

And here is the textfile

```
John Elway Dodge
123
2
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****


Tesla Cherry Creek
234
1
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Comment: In the debugger, the "2" and "1" are in the vector dealerOne, they are under the numberOfCars colomn!

Comment: The problem is probably in the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Dealer)`  function that you are not showing us.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < tempDealerOne.size(); i++) cout << tempDealerOne[0]<< "\n";`  Why are you printing the 0th item of the vector multiple times?  Shouldn't it be `for(int i = 0; i < tempDealerOne.size(); i++) cout << tempDealerOne[i]<< "\n";`

Comment: The `display()` function is outputting `tempDealerOne[0]` repeatedly - look carefully at what is in the `[]`.    It doesn't display anything else.   Voting to close as a typo.